# Explain 90th-percentile response time of 2 seconds when handling 200 concurrent connections per second

Tags: design, performance

From Ch 12 (Resiliency) of the book "Building Microservices"

In the context of how much resiliency is too much resiliency

> How long should various operations take? It can be useful to measure this with different numbers of users to understand how increasing load will impact the response time. Given the nature of networks, you’ll always have outliers, so setting targets for a given percentile of the responses monitored can be useful. The target should also include the number of concurrent connections/users you will expect your software to handle. So you might say, “**We expect the website to have a 90th-percentile response time of 2 seconds when handling 200 concurrent connections per second**.”

Can I translate above bolded sentence to "90% of 200 concurrent connections per second to have 2 seconds response time"?.

What does "90th-percentile" mean? is it against time? day? month?

Comment: No, you cannot. Well, you could, but not if you want both sentences to say the same thing. Note that the original is talking about a website and an expectation, your translation is not. I also think the original should contain: _"of 2 seconds or less"_ instead of _"of 2 seconds"_. Also, _"connections"_ is vague. Do the 2 seconds refer to the first time a connection is established, or does it refer to completed page downloads? Your question would be greatly helped if you told us why you need the translation, which is really a rephrasing.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have referenced source to my question.

Comment: Yes, that is useful. You can look up the word [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile). The correct rephrasing would be something like: _"We expect the response time of the website to be equal to, or lower than, 2 seconds in 90% of cases when there are 200 concurrent connections per second."_.

Comment: "90% of cases" - how could I practical say that my system can handle "90% of the cases"? I mean, I could say "out of 10k requests, 90% of the requests take <= 2 seconds" but from the phrase, its not clear what's the count of total requests?

Comment: @wenn32 "A reasonable number" - e.g. probably over a period of at least 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipKendall makes sense now.

Comment: Thanks @KIKOSoftware for clarification.

Comment: @wenn32 A percentage is expressed as a fraction of the total. It does not tell you what the total is, it tells you what fraction _of the given total_ needs to remain within the SLA. When you then find out what the total is (from some other source), you can apply the percentage to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate the 90th percentile,

- take all the requests
- order them by time taken, with the quickest first
- starting from the quickest go 90% of the way along that list
- read the time taken

So it translates as :

"Under a load of 200 requests per second, 90% of the requests will be responded to faster than 2 seconds."

It's a bit confusing because normally an application will have some rate of processing that it will run continuously at. Say each requests has a delay of 2 seconds built in. You could be running happily at 200 or 2000 requests per second. But at some point you have more requests coming in than can be dealt with with the given processing power and the application will start to error those extra requests, either through timeout or crashing.

Comment: Its primarily useful when the requests are either heterogeneous, non-deterministic timing, or there is jitter in the request rate. So if a request takes somewhere between 0.5 to 1.5 seconds to process, and the time between requests is somewhere between 5ms and 50ms, then there is a load level where the application may not pick up all requests immediately, but is able to take requests off a queue fast enough that the processing time + queuing time only ever exceeds the limit for a small percentage of slow requests during peak surges.

Comment: if you think about it those situations don't really define the stable rate. If your rate jitter is too high or the variation in processing time too great the app will fall over. So you would need to add a standard deviation or other metric to make quoting the rate pertinent to the response time

Comment: On aggregate over a 10-20 minute period there will be a stable average rate. Its just unstable on the second to second level. And yes you need to convey a measure of how much the data varies, thats what the 90% is. You care about the percentage of traffic that is within the 90% case. The standard deviation isn't really relevant because its not a normal distribution. If you need to convey how much its allowed to drop off by, then in my experiance you do that by expressing additional percentiles. 90% in xms, 95% in yms etc.

Comment: i think you are missing my point. theres no reason to think the 9xth percentile + rate indicates a max stable rate

Comment: and I think your missing my point, which is that it isn't really meaningful to define a hard max rate at which the system is stable. There's the max rate at which the system can serve every request as it comes in, but that is usually is considered as underutilising the hardware. Then theres the rate at which on average the requests will eventually get processed, but it may take an arbitrary amount of time to clear the backlog after a burst. (This arbitrary time is usually considered unacceptable)

Comment: Then between these two rates, there is a range where depending on the second to second system condition, the system may or may not be over the boundary line, whilst on aggregate over the minute to minute level remaining under it. The 9x percentile is saying that that flowing over only happens less than (10-x)% of the time, therefore is not a stable condition. But it still occasionally goes over temporarily. And that temporary condition is acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

The most common percentile that people encounter is also known as the 'median' value which is exactly the same as the 50th percentile.  You might also encounter quartiles and quintiles.

There's a good reason for using something like the 90th percentile.  Often people will use the 'mean' when analyzing performance but the mean, by itself can be very misleading because, in my experience, response times tend to follow something more like a [power law distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law) than a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).  You can have an average response time of 200ms while some requests are taking 10s to respond.  On the other side, if you look at the maximum time only, your outliers can cloud the picture of the overall performance and send you on goose chases for things that aren't worth fixing.  When doing performance analysis, I like to look at the median, 75th percentile and 90th.  It might even throw in the 99th percentile if it's a large set.

A good analogy for this kind of thinking about the height of a doorway.  If that height were the average height of a person, a large number of people would need to duck every time they go through the door.  If doorways were sized to be taller than the tallest person that has ever lived, we would have to greatly increase the cost of all construction in order to accommodate a very small number of people.  So, we use a height that works for almost everyone while understanding that some people will have to duck going through most doors.  When talking about service level agreements (SLAs) we instead pick a response time that is adequate for most needs.  The cost of ensuring no responses ever exceed that time is typically quite high so some percentile (such as 90th) is selected as the benchmark.

Comment: Regrettably the average response time isn't a good example of a power law distribution. Response times almost always follow a normal distribution, even they they are heavily [positively skewed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness). It always takes at least a bit of time to respond. There are better examples of a power law distribution, like like size of space junk around the earth: There are a few big pieces, quite a lot of mid-sized ones, but countless small flakes.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I didn't say the average response time is a power law distribution, I said the response time is.  And I'm talking about actual data I've looked at and it's definitely not normal.  Not even close.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "response time", not "average response time". I maintain that response times mostly follow a positively skewed normal curve, as I tried to say. Perhaps we're looking at the data in a different way? I was taking about [this kind of curve](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/early/2020/04/25/2020.04.23.056929/F1.large.jpg). A real version, is often not 100% normal, like that example, so there is a whole cottage industry trying to fit the curve with a mathematical formula.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'm not saying that what I've seen is typical but the data I've worked with is not normal based on statistical tests.  That's why I used the weasel words: 'in my experience'.  Long-tails to the extreme.  At one point I thought it was normal but because responses can't be negative, the 'left' part of the curve was chopped off but as I've looked more and more, it's almost a perfect power curve for most of the situations I deal with.  I think this has to do with a strong queuing effect (contention/blocking).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I've seen some response curves that look roughly normal, but they are the exception (I find that turn of words amusing...) Anyway, I'm interested in your assertion that response times are typically normal and how you get there.  If you are right, it might help point me to solutions.

Comment: I have a background in scientific research, cognitive psychology, specializing in [motor control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_control). Measuring the human response time is my bread and butter, and humans respond very "normal". Most natural systems do. Nowadays I do a lot of full stack development, and I see a lot of response graphs there as well.

Comment: Admittedly they often look like more a power law distribution, but as I said, even computers need a minimal time to respond. For a power law graph by far the most responses should be the smallest possible one, like one or two ms. However to show responses in the seconds the graphs don't show the details between 0 and 10 ms, and this makes them look like a power law graph, whereas in reality they aren't.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'm not talking about charts.   Statistical tests prove the data is not normal.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware We aren't talking about human response times (to a given stimulus). We are talking about software systems. A system's response time could be dominated by some calculation, the size of which depends on the parameters, and those can have whatever distribution, based on the domain